# How to use unique validation a column name

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `profiles` table and I have a `mobile` column name.

I want to validate unique `mobile` name.

```
    $validator = $request->validate([
        'phone' => ['required','unique:profiles,mobile',new CheckMobile],
    ]);
```

my client sending `phone` parameter.
but it doesn't check unique column.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel version 6 or higher try using a model name space instead of a table name

```
$validator = $request->validate([
    'phone' => ['required','unique:App\Models\Profile,mobile'],
]);
```

or try this

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$validator = $request->validate([
    'phone' => [
          'required',
          Rule::unique('profiles','mobile'),
     ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `|` instead of `,`:

Check docs:
[Writing The Validation Logic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation)

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'phone' => 'required|unique:profiles'
]);
```